# Not getting avro messages while reading data from topic in java

Tags: java, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I am writing code first time in java to consume AVRO data from kafka topic. I am using kafka-avro-console-producer to produce record.I am using leneseio/fast-data-dev image on Docker to UP kafka stack.

**Producing record :**

```
root@fast-data-dev / $ kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic payengine --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 --property value.schema='{"type":"record", "name":"payengine", "fields":[{"name":"tin", "type":"string"},{"name":"ach","type":"string"}] }'
{"tin":"61582","ach":"I"}
{"tin":"97820","ach":"I"}
```

Now, to read this record, I have written below code. Also, it seems like I don't have to refer the schema while consuming records (as mentioned in the below reference link). I had also gone through one example, where SpecificAvroRecord was being used in place of GenericRecord, but that requires building class based on schema. I am not sure how GenericRecord points to correct schema, but don't see any schema reference in the example.

```
package com.github.psingh.Kafka;

import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SimpleConsumer_AvroSchema {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.println("Hello Kafka ");

        // setting properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

        //name topic
        String topic = "payengine";

        // create the consumer
        KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, GenericRecord>(props);

        //subscribe to topic
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topic));

        System.out.println("Waiting for the data...");

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
            for(ConsumerRecord<String,GenericRecord> record: records) {

                System.out.print(record.value());

            }

           // consumer.commitSync();
        }

    }
}
```

The code built was successful.I was hoping to get console produced record here, but I am not getting anything :

[image]

Please suggest.

I have taken reference from here :

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html

Comment: Can you please share your `.avsc` AVRO configuration file

Comment: I am only passing schema while producing the record, it's in the console command. Will it required to be added while consuming record as well using GenerericRecord?